# Java daemon thread not picking up updated variable

Tags: java, caching, jboss

I have an in-memory cache(class Cache) in my prog, which is implemented as a singleton class which in turn uses a synchronized map. Till now, the timeout was set to 4 hours and was working fine. On trying to change it to 4 mins, the isTimedOut is behaving weirdly and is returning false(even after the accessed time is older than 4 mins). On debugging, I found that it is still using 4 hours as timeout. But, if I put a sysout in the isTimedOut method(say sysout("")) then the method is picking up the new value => 4 mins!

Any suggestions/pointers?

```
class Cache implements Runnable{
  public static final long timeout=4*60*1000;//4 mins
  static {

    cache = new Cache();
    Thread myThread= new Thread(cache );
    myThread.setDaemon(true);
    myThread.start();
  }

  private Map map = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap());

  public void add(CacheObj o){
    cache.add(somestr, o);
  }

  public void run(){
    if(cache.isTimedOut(){
      //delete from cache
    }
  }

  class CacheObj{
    Date accessedTime;
    boolean isTimedOut(){
      Date timeOut = new Date(accessedTime.getTime() + Cache.timeout);
      Date now = new Date();
      return (now.getTime() > timeOut.getTime());
    }
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: And post compilable code. Why is this cache a runnable? What's the point of this thread?

Comment: As JB Nizet already wrote, I don't understand the code either, maybe something is missing from the thread's logic. However, have you restarted the JBoss server between deployments or is the thread actually destroy on undeploy or is it still in the run method? That might cause inconsistencies when you debug because JBoss was unable to remove the old instance of it.

Answer (score 1):

If you changed it in the code it's likely to be a compilation or deployment issue.

try adding a JOptionPane.ShowMessageDialog("v1"); to see if jboss is actualy using your new code.